# call parent's function by child - React

Tags: reactjs

I want to call parent's function by a child.

Parent Class.

Here I have actions array that is creating columns in a child(eg: Edit column, which has < Edit /> as an icon ) and I want to call 
a onEditClick function of a parent when the user clicks on the edit icon.

```
onEditClick() {
    // this method should be called via child
}

render() {
    return (
      <Child
        actions={[
          {
            name: "Edit",
            icon: (
              <Tooltip title="Delete" className={classes.pointerStyle}>
                <Edit />
              </Tooltip>
            ),
            handler: "onEditClick"
          },
          {
            name: "Delete",
            icon: (
              <Tooltip title="Delete" className={classes.pointerStyle}>
                <DeleteIcon />
              </Tooltip>
            ),
            handler: "onDeleteClick"
          }
        ]}
      />
    );
}

//Child class
render() {
    return actions.map(col => (
      <TableCell style={{ marginLeft: "5px" }}>
        {col.icon} // here click event will occur
      </TableCell>
    ));
}
```

Comment: I have mentioned **handler** which I want to call. I don't want to use the props directly. I somehow want to use actions-prop then inside that I have handler that function I want to call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. You can pass `onEditClick` and `onDeleteClick` functions from parent inside actions array as handlers to your child component, and you can wrap your icon inside a button and pass that handler to button's `onPress`

```
    onEditClick = () => {}
    onDeleteClick = () => {}

    render() {
       return (
          <Child                
             actions={[
               {
                 name: 'Edit',
                 icon: <Tooltip title="Delete" className={classes.pointerStyle}>
                            <Edit />
                        </Tooltip>,
                 handler: this.onEditClick
                },
                {
                  name: 'Delete',
                  icon: <Tooltip title="Delete" className={classes.pointerStyle}>
                            <DeleteIcon />
                        </Tooltip>,
                  handler: this.onDeleteClick
                 }]
                }

            />
        );
}

// Child class
     render() {
        return (
           this.props.actions.map(col => (
                <TableCell style={{ marginLeft: '5px'}}>
                   <Button onPress={col.handler}> 
                     <View>{col.icon}</View>
                   </Button> 
                 </TableCell>
            )
           )                                         
        );
}
```

Comment: right! I have called like this `onClick={() => col.handler(row, i)}` but state is getting empty. any input ?

Comment: done. its working now. Need to do this ---> handler:  this.onDeleteClick.bind(this)

Comment: Can work without binding to this as well, if you use arrow functions

Answer (score 0):

You can call a parent function from the child component. You just need to pass the call-back method from the parent component using props and the call that method from the child. 
Here is an example:

parent.js:

```
onEditClick = () =>{}
render(){
  return(
  <child onEditClick={this.onEditClick}/>
)}
```

in Child.js:

```
 render(){
   return(
   <button onClick={this.props.onEditClick} />
 )}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy to do and also fairly common. You must first pass the function as a prop to in the child component. Once it is a prop, you may access it in the child component. Like so:

```
<Child parentFunction={this.onEditClick}>
```

Then to access inside the child component:

```
this.props.parentFunction
```

Whatever the prop name you choose is what you allows access to the function you specify inside the prop.